# Linking to External Sites in WebMatrix

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I am building a registry app for some of our external sites, but when I try to display the items I need; WebMatrix keeps adding localhost to everything. All of these sites are external from the app that I am building and would open in a new window/Tab when clicked on. How do I create the a href tag without it appending localhost to it and just using the URL I have in my DB?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you referring to `<a href="something">`, or are you referring to `@Href("~/something")`? Please provide more details and any relevant code.

Comment: If you are using `@Href("~/")` to link to external websites, then you're doing it wrong. You can't use `@Href("~/")` that way.

Comment: Could you please post the code you're trying to use to create the links?